# Bootstrap panel as dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to show the panel as dropdown, I tried it but some styles overlapping.

```
<div class"dropdown-menu panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">Notifications</h4>

  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    some list
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get panel in dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li>
        <div class"panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">Notifications</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                some list
            </div>
        </div>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Example:  http://codepen.io/imajedi4ever/pen/kIiLf/?editors=100